# Pyspark print a sentence with outputs

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am wanting to know and understand how you can print a sentence with the outputs within it.

For example:

I have the following code in which I get the final result as the a 1x1 table with
[state] [count]

I want to print the sentence
“[state] had [count].”

So the resultant state appears in [state] and the resultant count appears in [count]

I have tried things like:
df.print(xyz)

df.print(col(state) ....

df.show() is not what I am looking for because I want to print a resultant concatenated sentence

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a collect operation and the get the values.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("California", "312")], ["result", "count"])
df.show()

output = df.collect()

print(f"{output[0][0]} had {output[0][1]}")

+----------+-----+
|    result|count|
+----------+-----+
|California|  312|
+----------+-----+

California had 312
```